# Remove line break with new <p> tags

Tags: php, html, css

I have this PHP code on my website:

```
<?php
$usernametext = "<p style=" . '"' . "color:#969CB3;font-size:120%" . '"' . ">Username: </p>" . "<p style=" . '"' . "color:black;font-size:150%" . '"' . ">";
echo $usernametext . htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?>
```

But this is what it displays as.

[image]

I want it to be on one line and display like this.

[image]

The `<p>` tags (with styling) create a line break (or two) which I don't want. I have tried to put the `<p>` tags out of the PHP and had no luck. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use span tag instead of p tag

```
<?php
$usernametext = "<span style=" . '"' . "color:#969CB3;font-size:120%" . '"' . ">Username: </span>" . "<span style=" . '"' . "color:black;font-size:150%" . '"' . ">";
echo $usernametext . htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

the `<p>` is not the right one for your work you should use an inline tag such as `<span>`
see this it may be helpful

```
<?php
$usernametext = "<span style=" . '"' . "color:#969CB3;font-size:120%" . '"' . ">Username: </span>" . "<span style=" . '"' . "color:black;font-size:150%" . '"' . ">";
echo $usernametext . htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?>
```

and here is a Snippet for it

```html
<span>username is</span>
<span>XYZ</span>
```

```css
color:#969CB3;font-size:120%
```

```html
<span>username is<span>
  <span>XYZ</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, change p to span since by definition, each p represents a new paragraph (probabily there is a way to avoid line break when using p, but this approach doesn't pays off).

Answer (score 0):

add display :inline property for that ...

```
<style>
 p {
    display :inline;
  }
 </style>
<?php
$usernametext = "<p style=" . '"' . "color:#969CB3;font-size:120%" . '"' . ">Username: </p>" . "<p style=" . '"' . "color:black;font-size:150%" . '"' . ">";
echo $usernametext . htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?>
```